# Filter out null or undefined property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a property `bar` that can be `undefined` or `null`

```
const result = {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3',
    bar: await some?.http?.request?.that?.can?.be?.undefined?.or?.null
}
// outputs this
const result: {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3',
    bar: undefined ///  -> How to prevent this  from being added
}
```

I know I can do this

```
const result: {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3', 
}
const bar = await some?.http?.request?.that?.can?.be?.null?.or?.undefined
if (bar != null) {
    result.bar = bar
}
```

But is there a shorter (syntax) way ?

Also, this approach would not work if `result` is meant to be `immutable` once it is defined

Comment: Do you want to see an exception when it is null or undefined or just simply ignored?

Comment: Simply ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally add `bar` by firstly computing the value of `bar` (like you have in your second example):

```
const bar = await some?.http?.request?.that?.can?.be?.undefined?.or?.null
```

Then when you create `result` you use the ternary conditional operator to return an object with `{bar: <value>}` or an empty object `{}`, which you can then merge into the result object using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const bar = await some?.http?.request?.that?.can?.be?.undefined?.or?.null
const result = {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3',
    ...(bar != null ? {bar} : {}) 
}
```

See examples below:

```js
const bar1 = null;
const result1 = {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3',
    ...(bar1 != null ? {bar: bar1} : {}) 
};
console.log("bar 'null':", result1);

const bar2 = undefined;
const result2 = {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3',
    ...(bar2 != null ? {bar: bar2} : {}) 
};
console.log("bar 'undefined':", result2);

const bar3 = "foo4";
const result3 = {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3',
    ...(bar3 != null ? {bar: bar3} : {}) 
};
console.log("bar 'foo4':", result3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could as well decide on a later step what to do:

```
result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(result).filter( ([_,v]) => ( v!= null)))
```

And if the object is inmutable, you can just create a new one:

```
const defResult = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(result).filter( ([_,v]) => ( v!= null)))
```

But i'm afraid of that is not "shorter" as you asked

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate it in function to handle it more appropriately with ternary operator. The ternary operator will make sure that you don't get null or undefined.

```
const result: {
    foo1: 'foo1',
    foo2: 'foo2',
    foo3: 'foo3',
    bar: function(){
       const bar = await request();
       return (bar !== null || bar !== undefined)? bar: {};
    }
}
```